# Free a Windows heap without releasing memory pages

Tags: winapi, heap-memory

I'm implementing a heap pool utility and I need a *pool_clear()* function (like Apache Portable Runtime *apr_pool_clear()*). This functions allow us to free at once (single function call) all memory allocated on that pool without releasing memory pages to underlying system. Windows API only provides *HeapFree()* (multiple function calls) and *HeapDestroy()* (releases memory pages).

Are there any way to do it on Windows (using native API)?

Comment: By "free" do you mean "decommit the physical pages", or do you mean "mark as unused by the heap manager but keep physical pages committed"? (Note that "release" is different from both of these, it releases virtual address  space as well as physical memory.)

Comment: @Mehrdad, OP used [`apr_pool_clear`](http://apr.apache.org/docs/apr/2.0/group__apr__pools.html#gafa8a998cd660e82b62aecec09e239d0d) as an analogue, which leads me to believe he wants the memory left `VirtualAlloc`'d but allowed to be reused by the heap.

Comment: Don't you use VirtualAlloc etc. for this?

Comment: I create the heap with HeapCreate and I use it with HeapAlloc and HeapFree. What I'm asking for is a way to HeapFree all memory blocks allocated by HeapAlloc at once without calling HeapDestroy (I want to reuse that heap).

Comment: That's your problem. You need to take more control. Use VirtualAlloc etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`HeapCreate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and other [`Heap*`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366711%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functions from `Kernel32` don't provide this kind of power. They are meant to provide the same functionality as the C Standard Library, plus some extra debugging/diagnostic features.

It sounds like [`RtlCreateHeap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552159%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from `ntdll` would fit the bill, allocating the memory yourself and specifying a `HeapBase`, `InitialCommit`, `InitialReserve`, and `CommitRoutine`.

This means that you can call `RtlDestroyHeap` without it giving back all of the virtual memory, then, call RtlCreateHeap again with the same `HeapBase`, effectively, creating a new heap in the same virtual memory

Unfortunately, to my knowledge, these entry points in `ntdll` are **undocumented**, [as is most of the Native API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_API), so there is a risk associated with calling it. The linked documentation is for the entry point in `Ntoskrnl` for drivers to use. Since you explicitly call out using the Native API, maybe you understand and accept this sort of risk. In any case, it would almost certainly be safer to use a library that has already implemented this functionality.

If you are really serious about this sort of thing (which, frankly, scares me), you'll definitely want to look at [ReactOS's heap implementation](https://doxygen.reactos.org/d8/dc5/sdk_2lib_2rtl_2heap_8c_source.html) as a supplement to Microsoft's documentation.

Comment: There's no practical risk to using NTDLL, as much as Microsoft wants people to believe otherwise.

Comment: The practical risk of using undocumented features of windows is a real one: Nobody guarantees that the feature will be still available (and with the same functionality) in a future version.

Comment: This seems to be the only way using Windows native API directly. It's not not good news but I will accept it as the correct answer. I'll have to implement it with VirtualAlloc, VirtualFree and a custom allocator. Thanks.